# Mail is not sending in the forms add-ons in EE2 site?

Tags: email

I have EE2 site. Mail is stopped working in the forms addon but the mail is working in the EE because I have checked with Communicate Module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should verify the settings of the forms addon to select the "EE Internal" option for the "Email Library" field. Because the forms add-on uses the setting of the EE for that option.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answers.